# Specman e: How to print a pointer to a struct?

Tags: specman, e

I have the next message in my verification environment:

```
message(LOW, vt.text_style(LIGHT_PURPLE, " bla bla bla "), some_struct);
```

The output I get:

```
 bla bla bla  - some_struct-@405
```

I would like to add additional information to the message using `appendf` string routine, but then how can I print the address **some_struct-@405** (or whatever it is called)?

I'v tried `%x` but it caused compilation error:

```
message(LOW, vt.text_style(LIGHT_PURPLE, appendf(" bla bla bla %s %x ", new_info, some_struct)));
```

How can I print the pointer to the struct inside `appendf`?

Thank you for you help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just use `%s`. It can be used with all types, even structs. It actually calls `to_string()` for the relevant parameter, no matter what's its type.

`%x` means hexadecimal format, and can be used only with numeric types.